# In angular js want to set init variable

Tags: angularjs

```
<body ng-app="d" ng-controller="con" ng-init="jj=''">
    <section id="phase1">
                <div ng-repeat="obj in arr" >
                    <div  ng-if="jj != obj.sentdate" ></div>
                    <span  >{{obj.sentdate}}</span>    ///   how to set jj value here so that date print only once.
                    <div >{{obj.msg}}</div>
                </div>
            </section>  
</body>
```

This result

```
sat 14 2014
mookdsbg
sat 14 2014
mookdsbg
sat 14 2014
mookdsbg
```

But I want :

```
sat 14 2014
mookdsbg

mookdsbg

mookdsbg
```

Comment: Put the `ng-if` on the span-tag that actually outputs the date.

Comment: what u really need ?

Comment: see this link:  http://plnkr.co/edit/d4OYYv2axqEPBZFDkPJV?p=preview

i want same date print ones.

Answer (score 0):

```
<section id="phase1">
            <div ng-repeat="obj in arr" >
                <div  ng-if="jj != obj.sentdate" ></div>
                <span ng-show="jj != obj.sentdate" >{{obj.sentdate}}</span>    /// use ng-show
                <div >{{obj.msg}}</div>
            </div>
        </section>
```

Use ng-show for first repeat

Answer (score 0):

Replace this line in your plunkr.

```
 <div class="flickdate" ng-if="jj != obj.sentdate">
```

with

```
 <div class="flickdate"  ng-show="$index==1">
```

Edit : Sorry misread your requirement. use this..

```
<div class="flickdate" ng-show="arr[$index - 1].sentdate != obj.sentdate">
```

Comment: no, that not i mean.

if diffrent date further then date prints

means

sat 14 2014
mookdsbg

mookdsbg

sat 13 2014
mookdsbg


means print date then msg untill date changes. when date change prints that date and msg under that date

Comment: @PrateekGupta plz upvote  if it serves your purpose.